# Can I program the F10 button on my keyboard to input .com?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I am wondering if I can program the <kbd>F10</kbd>  button on my keyboard to input ".com" so when I type a website i can press <kbd>F10</kbd>  and ".com" will be put in. Is there a way? I am running Linux Lubuntu 15.04.

Comment: If you use Firefox, Control+Enter does what you mention.

Comment: Always or only in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to Ubuntu itself, this related to the Web brwoser you are using.

For example you can get the Firefox shortcuts from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)

```
Complete .com Address   Ctrl + Enter 
Complete .net Address   Shift  + Enter 
Complete .org Address   Ctrl  + Shift  + Enter 

Toggle Menu Bar activation (showing it temporarily when hidden) Alt (KDE) or F10  (GNOME)
```

As you can see you already have a shortcut for your need which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead  Firefox uses the shortcut <kbd>F10</kbd> to Toggle Menu Bar.

But if you really want to change the shortcut to meet your needs, you can find some extensions that help you, here is a link to [Customizable Shortcuts firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) which is used to change the shortcuts:

> Allows to customize or disable most of the shortcuts offered by
>   Firefox. This add-on does *not* allow to add new shortcuts, but it
>   might help you discover new ones.

The same procedure can be done for other web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, there is no separate NumPad. So I rarely use NumLock key. Hence I configured it in such a way that whenever I press NumLock, my username gets typed. But after subsequent Ubuntu re-installations/upgrades, I forgot about this, and now seeing your question, I've reimplemented it. This is how I did this:

Firstly, install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config xvkbd
```

Here, basically `xbindkeys` is a key grabber for X, `xbindkeys-config` is a GUI front-end, and `xvkbd` is a virtual keyboard for X, which can be used to simulate key strokes. Now execute this command to create the default config file for xbindkeys:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > /home/your-user-name/.xbindkeysrc
```

Now run `xbindkeys` from the terminal followed by `xbindkeys-config`.

The GUI front-end of `xbindkeys` shoots up. Add a new entry. The process should be self explanatory. Here is how that command entry in `Action` field should look like:

```
xvkbd -xsendevent -text "text-to-be-auto-typed"
```

`Apply` and `Save`. You are almost done. You need this hotkey to work even after reboot. On your dock, type `Startup Applications` and add an entry in which the command field will be `xbindkeys`.